# Select count from a table with a Where on another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I have two tables

- oc2_visits (fields: id_ad)
- oc2_ads (fields: published)

I need to count the visits by grouping the id_ad, and that works, but I need also that the first 9 results have been published not more that 25 days ago.

This is the query I have at the moment:

```
SELECT count(v.id_ad) AS visits,
       v.id_ad,
       a.published
FROM oc2_visits AS v,
     oc2_ads AS a
WHERE DATE(a.published) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY)
GROUP BY v.id_ad
ORDER BY visits DESC LIMIT 0,9
```

but when I try to enter the query in phpmyadmin, it crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it show any error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to parse `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY)` into `DATE` while comparing with a DATE. Hope it'll work.

```
SELECT count(v.id_ad) AS visits,
       v.id_ad,
       a.published
FROM oc2_visits AS v,
     oc2_ads AS a
WHERE DATE(a.published) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY))
GROUP BY v.id_ad
ORDER BY visits DESC LIMIT 0,9
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply adarsh, the problem persist, phpmyadmin crashes, the date seems to work anyways on other queries.

Comment: It might be some other issue then.(like: less internal memory or some configuration issues)

Comment: I don't think so, all other queries work and i'm on a good dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the root of your problem is the cartesian product between two tables.  Simple rule:  Never use comma in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

I imagine the query you want looks something like this:

```
SELECT count(v.id_ad) AS visits, v.id_ad, a.published
FROM oc2_visits v join
     oc2_ads a
     ON v.id_ad = a.id_ad
WHERE DATE(a.published) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY)
GROUP BY v.id_ad
ORDER BY visits DESC
LIMIT 0, 9;
```